# MongoDB to MongoDB document migration with Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, etl, pentaho-spoon

I have a document like this in DB01,MongoDb

[image]
I want to update this document in other MongoDB looking at a key(_id) inside the document.

My Pentaho job is really simple:
[image]

You can see that I get the data correctly.How can I update the whole document with the key to lookup _id for example?

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In your 'MongoDB Input' preview, I have seen your records has proper '_id' values. Ok, now you just need to select all fields instead of 'Output single JSON field' in your 'MongoDB Input' step.

And, in your 'MongoDB output' step, you need to set Y in 'Matching field to update' field for _Id.

I have prepare a sample Transformation for your [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nu8VFSanD0AI3rgB1z59YWPGzNQxmp4v?usp=sharing).

```
Before run my transformation do the following things:-
First create 2 collection with same '_id ' and different 'qty'.

db.products.insert( { _id: 10, item: "box", qty: 20 } )
db.products2.insert( { _id: 10, item: "box", qty: 2 } )

Take input from db.products and update record on db.products2 
only if '_id' is match.
```

Comment: Finally I did it by separating all the elements of the document and reloading it.

However, for me this is not functional, as there are some collections that have different elements and therefore I cannot map a document each time.
I would like to know an option to directly copy a document, without obtaining the data.